# Data array is cramming list of row values into one single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a button that will check a row of dates and search for today's date. once I have that date I plan to use its location to check for a list of received items for that day.[image] I am having trouble with my data array, which seems to be compiling all of the listed values across the row into a single object? When I check the values by hand(data[0][2], for example) it turns out a single date (12/2/18) as it should, but when I ask for data length, it returns 1 and the debugger is showing me that `data[1]` is "DECEMBER,12/1/2018,12/2/2018....". I am guessing that this is where my problem is, since I am using the data length property to initialize my loop. Basically, I need to know how to be able to access those column values, not just the row. Ideally I would want to be able retrieve the location of another cell based off of those counter values. So for example, something along the lines of - given r is row counter value and c is column counter value
`var today = dailySheet.getRange(r+1,c);`

Here is what I have so far:

```
function dailyButton(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RhhHuelCBVWWXQQQ9j3jiRCScsirofzwDleH-nxeLGw");
var dailySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Papers");
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth();
var mrange;
var strDate = Utilities.formatDate(d,"CST","MM/d/yyyy");
if (m == "10"){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A95:AF95");} //November
else if(m == "11"){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A104:AF104");} //December
var data = mrange.getValues();   
var dataLength = data.length;
Browser.msgBox("data02 ="+data[0][2]); //returns 12/2/18 correctly
Browser.msgBox("Data Length = "+dataLength); //returns 1
for( var c = 1; c < data.length; c++){ 
 if (data[0][c] == strDate) {
 Browser.msgBox(data[0][c]+" matches "+strDate);
  }
 }
}
```

Is there some other property similar to "length" that counts the array columns instead of just rows?

Comment: You are only getting 1 row so data length is 1.  data[0].length is 32.  getValues returns a 2D array the first index is the row and the second index is the column.  data[0][2] would be row 1 column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
function dailyButton0(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RhhHuelCBVWWXQQQ9j3jiRCScsirofzwDleH-nxeLGw");
  var dailySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Papers");
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMonth();
  var mrange;
  var strDate = Utilities.formatDate(d,"CST","MM/d/yyyy");
  if (m == "10"){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A95:AF95");} //November
  else if(m == "11"){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A104:AF104");} //December
  var data = mrange.getValues();   
  var dataLength = data.length;
  Browser.msgBox("data02 ="+data[0][2]); //returns 12/2/18 correctly
  Browser.msgBox("Data Length = "+dataLength); //returns 1
  for( var c = 1; c < data.length; c++){ 
    if (data[0][c] == strDate) {
      Browser.msgBox(data[0][c]+" matches "+strDate);
    }
  }
}
```

data.length is always 1 because data is an array that looks like [[col1,col2,col3.....]] i.e. its a single row.

I have a feeling that you want something like this:

```
function dailyButton(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RhhHuelCBVWWXQQQ9j3jiRCScsirofzwDleH-nxeLGw");
  var dailySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Papers");
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMonth();
  var mrange;
  var strDate = Utilities.formatDate(d,"CST","MM/d/yyyy");
  if (m == 10){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A95:AF95");} //November
  else if(m == 11){mrange = dailySheet.getRange("A104:AF104");} //December
  var data = mrange.getValues();   
  var dataLength = data.length;
  Browser.msgBox("data02 ="+data[0][2]); //returns 12/2/18 correctly
  Browser.msgBox("Data Length = "+dataLength); //returns 1
  for(var c=0;c<data[0].length;c++){ 
    if (data[0][c]==strDate){
      Browser.msgBox(data[0][c]+" matches "+strDate);
    }
  }
}
```

I ran the loop from 0 since getValues() returns a zero base array. So that data[0][0] is the value in column 1.  So my loop is `for(var c=0;c<data[0].length;c++)`.  So the data[0].length is the length of the first and only row.  So this allows you to iterate over all of the columns in the row.

I hope this helps.  If I'm incorrect about my assumptions let me know with a comment and I'll gladly remove my answer.